# Filtering URL value

Tags: sparql, wikidata

What I am trying to do is to select a certain entity for the certain condition. If the condition is url, then how I can make a proper query to get the only result that matches the v1 = "https://www.getmagicbullet.com/" .
The commented sentences are what I tried different ways, but only to fail. How could I adjust the query to get the right answer?
Thank you for your help.

```
    SELECT DISTINCT ?iLabel ?p ?v1
    WHERE {
        ?i wdt:P31 wd:Q212920.
        ?i wdt:P856 ?v1.
#       FILTER (?v1Label = "https://www.getmagicbullet.com/")
#        { ?v1 rdfs:label "https://www.getmagicbullet.com/"@en } 
# UNION { ?v1 skos:altLabel "https://www.getmagicbullet.com/"@en }
      SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ko,en,[AUTO_LANGUAGE]". }
    }
    LIMIT 1000
```

Comment: the bindings of `?v1` are URIs, thus, you have to use the URI in the filter expression: `FILTER (?v1 = <https://www.getmagicbullet.com/>)` - is that what you're asking? And w.r.t. to your `UNION` pattern, those *external* URIs don't have labels contained in the Wikidata dataset. So it does not work.

Comment: if you want to do string comparison on URIs, as you already should know from previous questions, use string functions in the filter, e.g. `FILTER(str(?v1) = "https://www.getmagicbullet.com/")` - clearly, this might be much slower than `FILTER (?v1 = <https://www.getmagicbullet.com/>)` which in fact is equivalent to use the URI  directly in the triple pattern, i.e. `?i wdt:P856 <https://www.getmagicbullet.com/>` where the triple store could make use of `pos` index

Comment: Oh, I see. Great. I didn't know that url always use blacket like <> Thanks